# css filter bug for firefox 3.6

Tags: css, firefox, browser, filter

I'm using this filter :

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'>
    <filter id=\'grayscale\'>
        <feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\' />
    </filter>
</svg>#grayscale");
```

And it makes my widget invisible on firefox 3.6.2, but for 3.5 on this link  http://jsfiddle.net/xDJzU/7/ it doesn't apply but it also doesn't make the widget invisible.

Do you know what rule to add or a workaround to solve this issue?

Comment: The latest version of Firefox is v24, and v3.6 was released in Jan. 2010, over *3.5 years* ago. Do you really need to use such an old version? I doubt many people are on such an old version anymore. It's likely that since [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) is still experimental, such ancient versions of Firefox might not have the best support of it.

Comment: If it makes a difference, the filter in your jsfiddle works fine for me in Firefox 24 on Linux.

Comment: It is strange indeed, but there are few people (very few) who don't know much about software and don't know how to do upgrades.

Comment: @ice13ill Hence my use of "I doubt many", instead of " I doubt any" :)

Comment: @ajp15243: Indeed, and it's unfair to call it a bug for that reason.

Comment: @BoltClock When did I call anything a bug? At most I suggested that the older versions of Firefox on which OP is testing *might* not support `filter` the same way recent versions of Firefox do. Edit: Nvm, misread the comment, I agree.

Comment: @ajp15243: You didn't - I was referring to the question title. My bad.

Comment: @BoltClock Derp, sorry, it's still early for me.

Comment: The problem is not that filter doesn't work, it's that it makes the widget invisible. It should just "do nothing".